# create a table with date name

Tags: mysql, database, stored-procedures

I am writing a simple procedure to backup a table-

```
CREATE PROCEDURE daily_backup()
BEGIN
   DECLARE given_date VARCHAR(25);
   SET given_date = now(); 

   CREATE TABLE given_date LIKE db1.table1;
   INSERT INTO given_date SELECT * FROM db1.table1;


END
```

But it creates a table with name given_date . I want to create a table with date as name. How to do the same ?

Comment: A date as a table name is not a valid SQL identifier. You should at least prefix it so that you don't get in trouble with non-standard names

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one

```
DELIMITER |
CREATE PROCEDURE daily_backup()
BEGIN
  SET @s = CONCAT('CREATE TABLE bak_', DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(), '%Y%m%d'), ' SELECT * FROM table1');
  PREPARE stmt FROM @s;
  EXECUTE stmt;
END
|
DELIMITER ;
```

**UPDATE**: You can make it run multiple times a day

```
DROP PROCEDURE daily_backup;
DELIMITER |
CREATE PROCEDURE daily_backup()
BEGIN
  SET @tbl = DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(), '%Y%m%d');
  SET @s = CONCAT('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS bak_', @tbl);
  PREPARE stmt FROM @s;
  EXECUTE stmt;

  SET @s = CONCAT('CREATE TABLE bak_', @tbl, ' SELECT * FROM table1');
  PREPARE stmt FROM @s;
  EXECUTE stmt;
END
|
DELIMITER ;
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/91f123/2)** demo

Answer (score 2):

generate create statement with prepare like :-

```
set @given_date = now();
SET @sql = CONCAT("CREATE TABLE ",@given_date," as SELECT * FROM db1.table1");
PREPARE stmt from @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
```

ps:- table name should be valid according [to this.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/identifiers.html)