# C# Escaping characters in parameters on mysql query for table name

Tags: c#, mysql

I'm making a simple mysql client to send some data.
I need my  tables to have the date as a name in this format: 2014-07-04

I know I have to wrap them around backticks(`) because of the (-).
Here's my code:

```
    public bool Update()
    {
        try
        {                
            MySqlCommand cmd = connection.CreateCommand();
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TbName", "");
            foreach (Employee emp in this.employees)
            {
                foreach(shift singleShift in emp.shifts) 
                {
                    cmd.CommandText = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS @TbName (id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, Name VARCHAR(40), aStart VARCHAR(5), aStop VARCHAR(5), Lunch VARCHAR(5), B1 VARCHAR(5), B2 VARCHAR(5), B3 VARCHAR(5));";                                                                    
                    cmd.Parameters["@TbName"].Value = singleShift.aDate; // singleShift.aDat = 2014-07-24                       
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();            
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return false;
        }
            return true;
    }
```

If I use this code, I get this error:

```
 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL       server version for the right syntax to use near ''2014-06-29' (id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, Name VARCHAR(40), aSta' at line 1
```

So I've tried with a few methods to solve this like using "`" to concatenate the parameter but I get this error:

```
 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''\`2014-06-29\`' (id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, Name VARCHAR(40), ' at line 1
```

and using MySqlHelper.EscapeString I get this error:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''\\\`2014-06-29\\\`' (id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, Name VARCHAR(40), ' at line 1
```

I know my tables should be named otherwise, but it is not possible in the current context.
What can I do to solve this?

Comment: Your tables should not be tables in the first place. Make a column "shift_date" and put all your data in one table. Quering your data when a piece of that data only exists as the table name will be a horrible mess.

Comment: @nvoigt But it will add a lot more rows. I mean for 14 different dates I have to store 300 employees with a Start,Stop, Lunch, + 3 Break times. Wouldn't that make it slow?

Comment: What do you think databases were built for :) Their one and only job is to store data. Don't try to be smarter than your database, that won't work. Get a good book on database design. If you find yourself creating tables dynamically, you are either somewhere on the bleeding edge (hint: managing personel is not the bleeding edge, that's as vanilla as it gets) or you are doing it wrong.

Comment: @nvoigt Thank you. I'm effectively pretty new to working with databases but I'm quite in a hurry to create this. Thank you for the advice, much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

[create a table with date name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17106254/create-a-table-with-date-name)

No, you can't use date as table name especially with -. Change to something else.